# Issues when installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu to a new Server.

Installation of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit desktop didn’t report any faults. However, the system cannot boot after installation. The screen stopped when filled with purple, and then USB power and VGA signal lost.

```
Installation of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit server: cannot enter the installation program. 
Errors reported:
udevd[355]: timeout: killing /sbin/modprobe -bc pci:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
then kernel panic of the installation program.
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You said that installation doesn't report errors then said that it reports. Please try recovery mode if you can and post outcome to the question body. Note that we need exact given messages to help.

Comment: I tried twice. The first version I installed is desktop version, which didn't report any error during installation. However, it failed to boot after that. So I switched to the server version, and it failed on the installation program. There may be hardware problems on the system, since I have been told just now that the server is using an alpha version of Intel's hardware.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to disable acpi or acpi ext in the advance settings? Sounds most likely like it is a video-usb conflict.